# formData object not sending all datas on firefox and IE

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest

i'm designing a web interface using only xhr functions for forms processing
while it's working perfectly on chrome, it has a very weird behavior on IE and firefox: not all datas are transmisted when submiting a form and there is nothing pointing to something specific when these errors occurs.

my post function looks like this:

```
function submitForm(formName,formTarget)  {
console.log(formName);
var form = document.getElementById(formName);
var formDatax = new FormData(form);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
document.getElementById("mainCenter").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
} else if (xhr.readyState < 4) {
document.getElementById("mainCenter").innerHTML = "<div class='loadingDiv'></div>";
}
};
xhr.open('POST', formTarget, true);
xhr.send(formDatax);

return false;
}
```

some forms are sent correclty, some others not (even very simple, like email/password login form)!

did anybody encoutered the same behavior or any clue to correct this ?

thank you !

Comment: Can you link to a page showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

finally found the cause:

if the `<form>` tag is placed after a `<table>` tag, it's not working. moving the form tag before the table tag solves the problem. if somebody has an explanation, just to understand this behavior :)

thank you !